# Copying Canvas to another scene make UI elements nonfunctional

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, canvas

When I copy a Canvas to a new Scene (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) in Unity, I cannot manipulate with UI elements inside this Canvas in a Game mode. If I only create a new Canvas everything will work fine. So the question is - is there any way to copy canvas with ui elements without loosing their functionality? It's important because there will be many scenes with similar UI elements.

Comment: do you have an EventSystem in the new scene as well?

Comment: Right! The problem was in EventSystem, thank you. I noticed that EventSystem doesn't copy to another scene by Ctrl+C / Ctrl+V. Should to create it each time.

Comment: you could place it inside the canvas so you won't forget to create it each time

Comment: No problem! glad it helped